# Joomla nginx rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, joomla, url-rewriting

I have a lot of joomla webs on one dir. And i transfer from apache to nginx. But now i have problem with rewrite on nginx. I need to all my joomla who is in subdir can use rewrite same like first web in public_html/ . It can work just for one. Is there solution who can set on all subdirs to use rewrite?

This is from my hostname.conf file on sites-enabled.

When i put rewrite for one web

```
  location / {
     expires 1d;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
```

Or some one in subfolders:

```
  location /test/test/test/ {
     expires 1d;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /test/test/test/index.php?$args;
  }
```

But i need rewrite so all joomla folders can work in all dirs. Because i have a lot joomla in my folder, and i need all in rewrite mod. I need solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you haven't followed yet, this is a good wiki to follow https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs_on_Nginx

Comment: This is for one web. My rewrite works with this rules, but i have more joomla in sub dirs. So they dont work because its writen in location to see just / (first dir)

Comment: Getting you. Not sure how to do that either for now. :(